# Prometheus : How to collect metrics for memory consumption of temporary processes?

Tags: java, grafana, prometheus

I have an application that spawns different processes asynchronously. When the process finishes, the response contains details of the process like memory consumed etc. I want to create metrics for the memory consumed by each process, based on the output. (Note: This means I can only update the metric only after the process finishes)

From the [Prometheus official document](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#gauge) I found that Gauge is the correct metric for such a measurement, when values go up and down arbitrarily. But the problem using Gauge is that the metric value stays there for ever. I want to track the value used by the process only for that instant of time.

When i plot the graph of Grafana, I see a steady line, when i only want a surge for an instant. Any suggestions to best solve this problem. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

For short-lived jobs that cannot be scraped normally using Prometheus, Prometheus provides the [push gateway](https://prometheus.io/docs/instrumenting/pushing/) which allows you to push metrics.

In your case, your short lived processes would push the reported metrics into the push gateway and Prometheus will handle the rest.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @yamenk. But I understand that this solution solves the problem of pushing the metrics. For me publishing the metrics is not a problem. The problem is the metric should have a short-lived value and should reset itself. Because it represents the value of an entity which is short-lived.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, this is my workaround:

I have created a metric of type *Counter* and I keep increasing the metric value by an absolute number(the actual memory consumed).

In Grafana I display the increase() every 1 minute.

If anyone has a more correct solution, please do tell.